# Wpf xaml window errors and warnings

Tags: .net, wpf

I've added resources to my window1.xaml file using MergedDictionaries like this:

```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\ListBox.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\ScrollBar.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\Button.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="\Resources\Slider.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I'm getting 4 errors for this code:

**Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.**

and 2 Warnings like this:

**The file '\Resources\Slider.xaml' is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'.**

The application is running fine and the resource dictionaries' build actions are set to "Resource".

Why am I getting these errors?

Using: vs2010, .net 4 on win7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the backslashes

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ListBox.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ScrollBar.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Button.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Slider.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```